# Pyspark apply a function on dataframe

Tags: python, function, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

My python method is below;

```
def leadtime_crossdock_calc(slt, wlt, dow, freq):
    temp_lt = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    remaining = []
    for i in range(0, 7):
        remaining.append((dow[i:] + dow[:i]).index(1))
    for i in range(7):
        if freq[i] == 1:
            supplier_lt = int(slt[i])
            warehouse_lt = int(wlt[(i + supplier_lt) % 7])
            waiting = int(remaining[(i + supplier_lt + warehouse_lt) % 7])
            temp_lt[i] = supplier_lt + warehouse_lt + waiting
    for i in range(7):
        if temp_lt[i] == 0:
            temp_lt[i] = next((value for index, value in enumerate(temp_lt[i:] + temp_lt[:i]) if value), None)
    return ''.join(str(x) for x in temp_lt)
```

And it turns for below example;

```
leadtime_crossdock_calc([0,2,0,2,0,3,0],[1,1,1,1,1,1,1],[0,0,1,0,1,0,1],[0,1,0,1,0,1,0])

'3333443'
```

The question is, i have a spark dataframe like below;

```
Product  Store  slt               wlt            dow              freq
A         B     [0,2,0,2,0,3,0]  [1,1,1,1,1,1,1] [0,0,1,0,1,0,1]  [0,1,0,1,0,1,0]
```

I want to create a new column for each new row in the dataframe using the above method;

```
Product  Store  slt               wlt            dow              freq              result
A         B     [0,2,0,2,0,3,0]  [1,1,1,1,1,1,1] [0,0,1,0,1,0,1]  [0,1,0,1,0,1,0]   [3,3,3,3,4,4,3]
```

Could you please help me about this? I couldn't apply the method for spark dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [User Defined Functions or UDF](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.UDFRegistration)
First register your UDF on spark, specifying the return function type. You can use something like this:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType, col
leadtime_udf = spark.udf.register("leadtime_udf", leadtime_crossdock_calc, StringType())
```

Then, you can apply that UDF on you DataFrame (or also in Spark SQL)

```
df.select("*", leadtime_udf(col(slt), ... , col(freq)))
```

Hope this helps